# Prevention against CSRF?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, csrf

I often use AJAX to write into MYSQL database like so

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "writescript.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { data : mydata,//this could be anything
     },
    success: function (html) {
      //do something
  }
});
```

And the `writescript.php` looks like this

```
$data=$_POST["data"];
//and then write into database.
```

Now this works and everything but then anybody can view the ajax request since it's pure JS and can be viewed from the page source. Given the information about the script name and parameters, an attacker could try to call the `writescript` as well and write into my database or read depending on what the script does. This is obviously not good. So am I missing something here? Is AJAX not designed to be used for such stuff? Or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a CSRF problem is presented here.  CSRF means an attacker tricking a legitimate and authenticated user into hitting a page by clicking a link or any other means, in turns doing things on behalf of them.  If your application checks for the header to make sure the request is an ajax call from the browser, and do not allow cross domain ajax requests, theoretically an attacker could not perform a CSRF attack

The problem you presented is more of an authorization problem.  You are afraid that an attacker can write/read into your database, but any legitimate users should be able to do that, so naturally the solution is to add an authentication layer to fend off attackers.

Comment: Of course, once you have an auth/authz system in place, you then need to add CSRF protection to it.

Comment: I get that, but is there a way to achieve this without having to differentiate b/w legitimate user and an attacker. More in terms of, whether the request was from an external source or from within my app itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "sessions". You can use sessions or any other authentication method to avoid this case. That is, be sure that the user is logged in at the beginning of the php code.

Answer (score 0):

When user requests the page, generate a security token on that page and note it on the server. Then the response comes back, just compare the recieved security token with the saved one.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet